# Router not responding to DNS queries?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I'm trying to build a VPN with zerotier since I don't have a public IP. I have an ASUS router at home with zerotier installed which joined the network with ip (`192.168.195.208`). I'm currently trying to direct all the traffic on the virtual network through the router and also use it as the DNS.

I'm testing on a MacBook from office and I tried setting some DNS rule on the control panel for youtube to use my router as DNS, but it does not work, I can see with running tcpdump on the router that the query is still to the local DNS. Then I manually modify my DNS to `192.168.195.208`. I can see the router receiving dns queries with the correct dst which is `192.168.195.208` but it's not responding at all, while it's fine with all other devices at home.

I really have no clue how this is happening. The connection is all fine, I can even stream with PS5 pretty well. I also checked iptables and there does not seem to have rules that can lead to the queries being dropped. I've searched the internet for several days and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It's the configuration of the dnsmasq on the router. It's not listening to the interface of zerotier.

In my case, I checked my configuration file of dnsmasq under

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.

Here is a line that points to the directory of custom config.

`conf-dir=/jffs/configs/dnsmasq.d`

Then create a file `my.conf` under that directory with a line `interface=zt_interface`. You can check the name with `ifconfig`.

Then run `service restart_dnsmasq` to restart dnsmasq service. Problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).